# Form submit button not working with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I've a problem with my form. I want to make standard PHP form but AngularJS is blocking the "Submit" button.

When I click the "Submit" button, it returns some errors in console. And remember I don't want to dynamically submit.

The error is:

> An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.

This example

```
<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <form action="post.php" method="post">
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <label for="titlex">Title</label>
            <input id="titlex" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="75" min="10" name="titlex" required>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try to add a name attribute to the button? **<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">**

Comment: Really thank you so much. I did what you said and the button worked. I can not believe it's that simple. I've been trying for almost 2 hours :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This issue pops up in different cases:**

- You have a hidden form element that has a `required` attribute for validation.
- You hide an form element before `send` your data.
- Some required form elements does not have a `name` attribute.
- Your submit `input` does not have a `name` attribute.

You can try to add a `name` attribute to your submit input:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
```

or you can setup your form to be not  validated by the browser mechanics by using

```
<form name="myform" novalidate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `name` attribute in input tag. 
Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
```

Hope this solves your problem.